# python problems in vs

Tags: python, tensorflow

Getting this error while running in visual studio

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
Stack trace:

> File "C:\Users\spt\source\repos\GIDEON_v01\GIDEON_v01.py", line 8, in 
>      import tensorflow as tf
>   Loaded '**main**'
>   Loaded 'runpy'

Comment: Which version of python and tensorflow are you using?

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: @HeisAif the latest version

Comment: @HeisAif windows 10

Comment: TensorFlow is tested and supported on the following 64-bit systems:

Python 3.5–3.7

Comment: If you using python greater than 3.7 try downgrading it.

Comment: Provide the full stacktrace not the last bit. there should be another exception happening that cuased this.